# How do I access parent methods inside this ES5 class?

Tags: node.js, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I have a Babel ES5 class setup in NodeJS like:

```
import fs from "fs";

// Services
import { aws } from "../../services/aws";

class UserController {
    update(req, res, next) {
        const { user } = req.body;

        if (user) {
            req.user = Object.assign(req.user, user);

            req.user.save((err, updatedUser) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(422).json(err);
                }

                return res.json({ user: updatedUser });
            });
        } else {
            return res.sendStatus(400);
        }
    }

    testMethod() {
        this.update();
    }
}

module.exports = new UserController();
```

How do I access the 'update' method from inside another parent method? It's difficult to see how 'this' is defined in this case

Comment: This depends on how exactly testMethod is used. This is ES6, not ES5.

Answer (score 0):

Using `this` as you present in `testMethod` will work.

If you want to ensure you are calling your singleton exported by your module, you can hold an instance and call it.

Of course, if you create another instance, this approach will fall apart.
In your case, you have not exported your class, so no client will be able to create it anyway.

```
const userController = new UserController()

// class definition here...

// In your class definition, use `userController` instead of `this`.
// For example

testMethod() {
    userController.update()
}

module.exports = userController;
```

Comment: Great point. I think he is asking to explain how "this" works inside a class for accessing other methods of the same class, but I'm not sure; the question is not fully clear.

Comment: The benefit of using this approach is that you can call it unambiguously from inner classes, or even from other classes, or from no class at all.

Comment: Correct I was asking the context of this inside a method. This approach I find is much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

When you create methods inside a `class` in JavaScript, `this` refers to the instance of the class itself. Therefore, you can access all definitions on the `class` from any method within it.

**Classes are really just functions with syntax sugar.** [Check here for a thorough explanation of how classes work](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-classes-in-javascript), including the usage of `this`.

You can use a constructor to define variables for the class, like so:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(name) {
    // setting a value on "this", which refers to the class object
    this.name = name;
  }

  printName() {
    // logging "this.name" which we set in the constructor
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

const myObject = new MyClass("Michael");
myObject.printName(); // prints out "Michael"
```

See how `this` works both in the constructor and in the class method?

These class methods are actually just shorthand for defining a function assigned to `this` from the constructor.

Using your example, here's what actually happens:

```
class UserController {
  constructor() {
    this.update = function(req, res, next) {
      const { user } = req.body;

      if (user) {
          req.user = Object.assign(req.user, user);

          req.user.save((err, updatedUser) => {
              if (err) {
                  return res.status(422).json(err);
              }

              return res.json({ user: updatedUser });
          });
      } else {
          return res.sendStatus(400);
      }
    }

    this.testMethod = function() {
      this.update();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 'this' does not refer to the 'class', it refers to the 'instance' of the 'class'.

Comment: Thank you @StevenSpungin, I fixed my answer.